# How to get correct status messages for a Python script?

Tags: python

I have a part of a Python script. This script will be invoked using a shell script.

```
try:
    sqlContext.sql("create table {}.`{}` as select * from mytempTable".format(hivedb,table))
except Exception as e:
    status = 'fail'
    error_message = e
else:  
    status = 'success'
    error_message = 'No error'
print ("{},{},{},{}".format(hivedb,table,status,error_message))

status == 'success'
sys.exit(1)
```

In this above code if I use `status == 'success'` I am getting `success` for all the time when the script runs, even for failed jobs.

If I use `sys.exit(1)` or both together I am getting failed all the time.

What should I do to get the script execution to be successful when `status` is `'success'` and fail when `status` is `'fail'`?

Comment: ...`if status != 'success': sys.exit(1)`? Also **do not** use `str.format` to build SQL queries, use the parameterisation provided by whatever library you're using.

Comment: @jonrsharpe your comment works for me. I got a small doubt, In the above code I would like to print `error_message` separately. I mean I want it to show on the `console` but not as an output of the script

Comment: Separately to what? What precisely is your *"small doubt"*? What have you tried to dispel it? *"I want it to show on the console but not as an output of the script"* - it's unclear what distinction you're drawing there.

Comment: @jonrsharpe when I run the `python` script on a `Linux` terminal I will get output of the result of this `print ("{},{},{},{}".format(hivedb,table,status,error_message))` on the console.
Now what I want is the `error_message` to appear on the console logs also. But when I put `print error_message` in the code then I am getting it together with `print ("{},{},{},{}".format(hivedb,table,status,error_message))`
Which I don't want. I want the `error_message` only in the console logs not on the console.

Comment: That makes absolutely no sense.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer would be to remove the the try/except. If you just make the call, on an exception, you'll get the full traceback to stderr and python will exit with a non zero exit status.

E.g.

```
$ python -c "raise Exception('ha');" 1>stdout 2>stderr
$ echo $?
1
$ cat stderr
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
Exception: ha
```